# Not able to install Python3 on AIX server

Tags: python, server, installation, aix

I am trying to install Python 3 on a AIX server.

I got the Python 3 RPM file for AIX from [here](https://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/date.html).

There were few dependencies that needed to be installed before installing Python, but I chose to install it without having installed any dependency through nodeps.

Now when I execute a Python3 command, I get the following errors:

[image]

It says cannot load module /opt/freeware/lib64/libpython3.5m.so but the file does exists in that directory.

[image]

Both `LIBPATH` & `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` are set to lib64.

[image]

Edit: Adding the output of lslpp -L rmp.rte command

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue has been resolved now :)

I downloaded and installed below 2 dependencies
[libgcc](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc-7.2/gcc/libgcc-6.3.0-1.aix7.2.ppc.rpm)
[gettext](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/RPMS/ppc/gettext/gettext-0.19.7-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm)

I need not had to downgrade RPM or install and use yum to download required dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Download 3.0.5.51 from [here](ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/INSTALLP/ppc/rpm.rte.3.0.5.51)

After download execute the following command on the server as root:

```
# installp -acFXYd rpm.rte.3.0.5.51 all
```

This command should downgrade your RPM to 3.0.5.51 and make it usable.

Comment: Is this the only way to make it work? There is no other way apart from downgrading RPM?

Comment: There might be, but when I had this issue in the past this fixed it. I'll try to find another solution if you need me too but if you urgently need it to work I'd suggest using my answer

Comment: Yes, please .Could you please help me finding another solution? Because downgrading RPM in production server would not be recommended.